# How can I set a flexible grid-column-gap between fixed-size grid columns?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-grid

I've got a layout with three columns and two rows -- the columns should be a fixed size, but I'd the `grid-column-gap` between the columns to be responsive but not go below a minimum size.  I tried to use something like the following, but `minmax` doesn't seem to work here (my IDE flags it as a bad usage too).  Thanks for any clues!

```
.mainGrid-main {
  max-width: $max-width;
  width: $max-width;
  grid-column-gap: minmax(76px, 1fr);
  grid-row-gap: 89px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, $cardWidth);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: '0 1 2' '3 4 5';

  $areas: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5;

  @each $area in $areas {
    .mainGrid--card-#{$area} {
      grid-area: #{$area};
    }
  }


}
```

Comment: An [MCVE] would be useful here but I'd suggest that you should be removing the `gap` and using `justify-items:center.` There is no min/max for `gap` or `margin` - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: @Paulie_D -- Thanks, you're right, but that was pretty much what I wanted to know, if I was barking up the wrong tree.  I can pursue a different avenue.